# Nginx proxy_cache miss if URI has slash

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

My nginx location block is:

```
location ^~ /get/preview {
    add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

    proxy_buffering on;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Set-Cookie;

    proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;

    proxy_cache upstream;
    proxy_cache_key $scheme$host$uri$is_args$args;
    proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD;
    proxy_cache_min_uses 0;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 301 302 1h;
    proxy_cache_use_stale updating;
    proxy_cache_background_update on;
    proxy_cache_lock on;

    proxy_pass https://tar.backend.com;
}
```

This will be a **HIT** after the 1st request:

> https://example.com/get/preview?fileId=17389&x=256&y=256&a=true&v=5fe320ede1bb5

This is always a **MISS**:

> https://example.com/get/preview.png?file=/zedje/118812514_3358890630894241_5001264763560347393_n.jpg&c=5fe3256d45a8c&x=150&y=150

Answer (score 0):

You should check "Expires" header from your upstream. Documentation said "parameters of caching may be set in the header fields “Expires” or “Cache-Control”."

Another option - maybe you have another location for .(png|jpg|css|js)$ files with different options.

Comment: `proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Set-Cookie;` is already ignoring upstream headers, and i don't have any location for static files. Thanks.

Comment: What about Expires header?